# J2ME development without Java?

Tags: java, java-me, jvm, functional-programming, jvm-languages

I'm making my first foray into the J2ME world. I'd prefer to use a functional language to do the development.

Scala used to have CLDC support, but it's no longer maintained. Bigloo seems to have disappeared.

Interpreters (such as Jython) are a no-go, since J2ME apps have to be small (at least, mine has to be).

I would like to know of anyone who has been able to use another JVM language to build J2ME apps.

Answer (score 2):

Running a different language on top of CLDC might be cool but the devices are usually very constrained in memory and CPU that this is merely impossible.

Look forward to [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/) which will bring new wind to mobile marketplace. For existing handsets you have to use Java ME.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Symbian, you can try [Python for S60](http://opensource.nokia.com/projects/pythonfors60/)

Answer (score 1):

Java is one of the most widely available runtimes. So if your app is aimed at a wide range of Handsets you should indeed choose Java ME. If you are targeting a particular make/model you could have other choices. 
For example, The [Symbian OS](http://www.forum.nokia.com/I_Want_To/Develop_Mobile_Applications/Get_Started.xhtml#professional_developer), can take a number of runtimes and you could develop using open C/C++ amongst others. Check the link.
Probably I am late in answering this one and your project is already under way.