# Is there any language other than Java that will work as ubiquitous on mobile?

Tags: java, android, programming-languages, blackberry, mobile

I'm trying to write a rogue-like game for my blackberry and hopefully
any other phone that supports some sort of JVM.

Because I use Java in my job I'm looking to write the game in another language but I cannot find a language that will work on multiple phones.

Am I stuck with Java?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318887/j2me-development-without-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're programming for Android, you could for example use Scala, see [Scala on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476111/scala-programming-for-android). Scala compiles to Java bytecode. There are also other languages which can be compiled to Java bytecode; I don't know how well-suited they are for Android programming.

Comment: Do I than convert the byte code to dex or what ever the dalvik format is?

Comment: This might be the best option because I really like Scala. I'll probably just have to wait for Blackberry to suck less.

Comment: Yes, interestingly the dalvik compiler operates on the .class files, not on the raw code.  All you have to do is run the dx tool (in the android sdk) on the class files generated by the Scala compiler.  The bigger limitation is going to be Blackberry.  AFAIK Java is the only language you can write Blackberry apps in...

Comment: @Chris - you can always edit your comments.  Or copy-delete-paste-add them.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use another language for the Java platform. Unfortunately you'll be rather limited there as well, because J2ME is based on a rather ancient version of Java SE and most modern languages for the Java VM need either Java 5 or at least Java 1.4.

Comment: But Android is not J2ME, it's more than that.

Comment: @Jesper: granted, but the BlackBerry API is based on J2ME and since he's talking about Java+Android+BlackBerry I was assuming he's interested in a common ground.

Comment: I do like scheme but I would prefer clojure.

Answer (score 0):

[Lua](http://www.lua.org/) runs very well on small devices (I use it on my handheld), but it is designed to be coupled into a C API.  You may well have to write glue code yourself, which is easy, but if the official APIs are Java APIs and there *is* no C API, you'll be out of luck.

Comment: I just don't like Lua that much. But I appreciate the answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually C++ is pretty universally supported at this point.  However you are completely stuck with Java for Blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I think the second (JavaME being first) most widely deployed runtime worldwide is Flash Lite.

Whether it would be a good idea to use it for your game development is another matter entirely of course.

Number three is Symbian OS C++ but that won't work on your Blackberry.